# Highcharts - How to remove tooltip arrows

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a custom HTML tooltip with Highcharts and would like to remove the arrow, e.g. see the tiny arrow over the blue bar:

[image]

These are my settings for the current tooltip:

```js
    useHTML: true,
    shadow: false,
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    style: {
        padding: 0
    },
    shared: true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use option *shape*

```
shape: "square"
```

[Highcharts reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip)